# Not able to verfiy keys of dictionary with a string returned by function

Tags: python, subprocess

**Use case**:
Using python subprocess module,get the vendor name by executing commands over adb, verify that vendor exist in already existing dictionary.

**Python class**

return value from **check_operator** would be verified in **self.dict1** inside **test_dict** function

```
from subprocess import Popen,CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE
import subprocess
class test:

    def  __init__(self):
        self.dict1={'airtel':6,'voda':2}
        self.terminal='cmd'
        self.value=''

    def check_operator(self):
        print 'checking operator...'
        self.procId =Popen('adb -s FA67MBN03500 shell', stdin = subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate('getprop gsm.sim.operator.alpha\n exit')[0]
        print type(self.procId)
        print self.procId
        return self.procId

    def test_dict(self,sim):
        self.value=sim
        print '##########'
        print self.value
        if self.value in self.dict1:
            print 'yes'
        else :
            print 'No'
```

When i run this class

```
abc=test()
a=abc.check_operator()
```

Output

> ```
> checking operator...
> <type 'str'>
> airtel
> ```

```
abc.test_dict(a)
```

output

> ```
> ##########
> airtel
> No
> ```

Can anyone please suggest what is wrong in my code , i am expecting **"yes"**
here.

**Expected output**

> ```
> ##########
> airtel
> Yes
> ```

Comment: What's the output of `print(repr(self.value))`? Try setting `self.procId = self.procId.strip()`.

Comment: Did you try `self.value=sim.strip()` ?

Comment: @Aran-Fey strip() did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to replicate the issue locally but I'm getting the correct output. So the only issue I see is the output of check_operator might have some extra characters attached to it such as space. Check if self_value is 'airtel' in test_dict.

```
from subprocess import Popen
import subprocess

class test:

  def __init__(self):
    self.dict1 = {'airtel': 6, 'voda': 2}
    self.terminal = 'cmd'
    self.value = ''

  def check_operator(self):
    print('checking operator...')
    self.procId = Popen('adb -s FA67MBN03500 shell', stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate('getprop gsm.sim.operator.alpha\n exit')[0]
    print(type(self.procId))
    print(self.procId)
    return self.procId

  def test_dict(self, sim):
    self.value = 'airtel'
    print('##########')
    print(self.value)
    if self.value in self.dict1:
        print('yes')
    else:
        print('No')


abc = test()
abc.test_dict('airtel')
```

Console Output:

> #
>
> airtel
>   yes

Comment: Problem was that the adb command was returning some special characters , i used return self.procId.strip() and the issue is resolved now.

Comment: Glad to hear that!